# bash echo with escape backtick and $

Tags: shell, sed, sh, echo

**test.sh**

```
COMMAND1="Build `date`"
COMMAND2="echo $PATH"

echo "Command1 is: $COMMAND1"
echo "Command2 is: $COMMAND2"
```

**output**

```
Command1 is: Build Wed Dec 26 21:09:43 UTC 2018
Command2 is: echo /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

In above shell script, how can I echo without evaluating the expressions i.e. I want `` Command1 is: Build `date` ``

I understand I can escape the `` ` `` and the `$` character, but in my application they are coming from an upstream service and passed as an argument to the shell script. Even the upstream service cannot escape them because later in script I actually need to execute these commands.

The ideal way would be to tell echo to only expand the variable `$COMMAND1`, but do not evaluate anything inside it. Or use **`sed`** to escape all occurrences of `` ` `` and `$`, but I haven't been able to achieve either.

Comment: Note that storing commands in string variables is considered bad practice -- it's innately error-prone. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for a discussion of how and why it's buggy, and available alternatives.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the link. The `set -x` option is interesting. I will try that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression is evaluated on assignment.

```
COMMAND1="Build `date`"
```

The `` `...` `` is a command substitution and is deprecated in favor of `$( ... )` style. The `"` doublequotes are used to allow the text to be expanded. So first this command is expanded to:

```
COMMAND1='Build Wed Dec 26 21:09:43 UTC 2018'
```

Then the assignment happens. You can't retrieve later what command was used to declare the variable. That information is lost. If you have some upstream - it needs to pass this information to you along.

If you wish for `COMMAND1` to contain the string (literally)

```
Build `date`
```

You can use single quotes:

```
COMMAND1='Build `date`'
```

You can later use some combination of `eval` or similar to expand the variable, however I would suggest to just do a function

```
COMMAND1() {
   Build $(date)
}

echo "COMMAND1 is declared as:"
declare -f COMMAND1
echo "COMMAND1 execution returns: $(COMMAND1)"
```

Helpful links:

- [Quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
- [Eval command and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)
- [Why is $(...) preferred over `...` (backticks)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. So your suggestion of using single quotes and then `eval` works perfectly. I didn't understand your second suggestion to use functions. Also I am in alpine, so `declare` doesn't work for me. Any other alternative to `declare`? Also give me some time to experiment more before I accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Busybox's shell is much restricted version of posix shell. I find on docker is has `type`, but nothing which would allow to print a function declaration. For declare builtin, you would need to install bash. If you go with `eval` - be prepared to properly escape your commands. Maybe better solution is a subshell `sh -c "$COMMAND"` will double-interpret the argument too and work if the command shouldn't affect current environment.

Comment: If you *do* need `date` evaluated later, I would restructure the code and define a function that you call when you are finally ready for the date. Avoid `eval` wherever possible.